# Binary Search Tree with Key Value Pair Insert Method

Tags: java, insert, binary-search-tree, key-value

This question is how do I create a new node correctly to implement the insert method? I am using eclipse IDE to write this code, but I am stuck.

```
    public KeyValueDSBinarySearchTree(Class<K> keyType,
                               Class<V> valueType,
                               DSComparator<K> keyComparator) {

        ObjectTools.paramNullCheck(keyType, "keyType");
        ObjectTools.paramNullCheck(valueType, "valueType");
        ObjectTools.paramNullCheck(keyComparator, "keyComparator");

        rootNode = null;
        count = 0;
        levelCount = 0;

        lastReplacedPair = null;
        lastDeletedPair = null;
    }


    @Override
    public DSKeyValuePair<K, V> insert(K key, V value) {

        DSKeyValuePair<K, V> node;

        if (rootNode == null) {
            count++;
            return node;
        }
        if (key.compareTo(node.getKey())<0) {
            rootNode.left = insert(key, value);
        }
        else {
            rootNode.right = insert(key, value);
        }
        return node;

    }
```

Comment: Please format your code, add programming-language tag, and post [mcve]